# Slices from keys of a multidimensional dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to assign and retrieve slices of data using two keys, and I do not *a priori* know the values for one of the keys.

Specifically, I'm downloading and processing text data files that list float values by year and duration (e.g., 1 hour). The duration keys are predetermined, but the years are not. The data are provided sequentially, one line at a time (not tabular, in other words).

Because I don't know all the years in a given file, so far I've tried using defaultdict(dict). Here's my sample code.

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(dict)

a[2006][2]=0.024
a[2004][2]=0.157
a[2000][1]=0.64
a[2005][2]=0.346
a[2003][2]=0.165
a[2003][6]=0.8
a[2007][12]=0.642
a[2003][1]=0.664
a[2002][6]=0.579
a[2004][1]=0.829
a[2001][6]=0.344
a[2003][3]=0.508
a[2003][12]=0.66
a[2002][1]=0.923

:a

defaultdict(dict,
            {2006: {2: 0.024},
             2004: {2: 0.157, 1: 0.829},
             2000: {1: 0.64},
             2005: {2: 0.346},
             2003: {2: 0.165, 6: 0.8, 1: 0.664, 3: 0.508, 12: 0.66},
             2007: {12: 0.642},
             2002: {6: 0.579, 1: 0.923},
             2001: {6: 0.344}})
```

I need to do three things.

1. Retrieve all the year keys. Remember I don't know them ahead of time.
2. For each year, retrieve the duration key:value pairs. I figured that one out.

   ```
   : a[2002]

   {6: 0.579, 1: 0.923}
   ```
3. For each duration, retrieve the year key: value pairs. I'm stuck on this one.

I appreciate any help you can offer. If I should be doing this in numpy, pandas, or something else, feel free to redirect me. Keep in mind I don't know the year range ahead of time, and even if I did there are random gap years with no data.

Comment: not sure I'm understading...why cant you just do dict.keys() to get the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for, but for getting all the year keys and their values you can iterate over that dictionary, by doing like this:

```
for i in a:
    print(i, a[i])
```

Output:

```
2006 {2: 0.024}
2004 {2: 0.157, 1: 0.829}
2000 {1: 0.64}
2005 {2: 0.346}
2003 {2: 0.165, 6: 0.8, 1: 0.664, 3: 0.508, 12: 0.66}
2007 {12: 0.642}
2002 {6: 0.579, 1: 0.923}
2001 {6: 0.344}
```

Comment: @IndianaBones *output for key 1 might look something like this:*, look like what?

Comment: Thanks! That actually takes care of my first and second 'need'. I'll have some code that checks the key:values pairs for each year, and modifies the values under certain circumstances. But I have no idea how to efficiently do the next step, which is retrieve all the values associated with the second key. For example, the output for key **1** might look something like this:
`
{2000: 0.64, 2002: 0.923, 2004: 0.829, 2003: 0.664}
`
Or something else I can parse. But maybe I'm asking too much of a dictionary here, so numpy/pandas alternatives are welcome.

Comment: Zamir, see my repost. I'm brand new to stack exchange and I didn't realize there was an editing time limit.

Answer (score 0):

```
from collections import defaultdict
a = defaultdict(dict)

a[2006][2]=0.024
a[2004][2]=0.157
a[2000][1]=0.64
a[2005][2]=0.346
a[2003][2]=0.165
a[2003][6]=0.8
a[2007][12]=0.642
a[2003][1]=0.664
a[2002][6]=0.579
a[2004][1]=0.829
a[2001][6]=0.344
a[2003][3]=0.508
a[2003][12]=0.66
a[2002][1]=0.923

print(a)

"""

defaultdict(<class 'dict'>, {2006: {2: 0.024}, 2004: {2: 0.157, 1: 0.829}, 2000: {1: 0.64}, 2005: {2: 0.346}, 2003: {2: 0.165, 6:0.8, 1: 0.664, 3: 0.508, 12: 0.66}, 2007: {12: 0.642}, 2002: {6:0.579, 1: 0.923}, 2001: {6: 0.344}})

"""

# Retrieve all the year keys. Remember I don't know them ahead of time.

for item in a:
  print(item)


"""
2006
2004
2000
2005
2003
2007
2002
2001
"""


# For each year, retrieve the duration key:value pairs. I figured that one out.


for year in a:

  dur_key_val = a[year]

  print(year,'=>',dur_key_val)

# For each duration, retrieve the year key: value pairs. I'm stuck on this one.

durationDict  = {}

for year in a:


  dur_key_val = a[year]

  for inner_key in dur_key_val:

    duration = dur_key_val[inner_key]

    durationDict[duration] = { year:inner_key }


print(durationDict)


"""
{0.024: {2006: 2}, 0.157: {2004: 2}, 0.829: {2004: 1}, 0.64: {2000: 1}, 0.346: {2005: 2}, 0.165: {2003: 2}, 0.8: {2003: 6}, 0.664: {2003: 1}, 0.508: {2003: 3}, 0.66: {2003: 12}, 0.642: {2007: 12}, 0.579: {2002: 6}, 0.923: {2002: 1}, 0.344: {2001: 6}}
"""
```